# Populating Highcharts chart with data received from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, highcharts

I'm new to web programming and this thing here is for my bachelor's degree project. I am doing an electrical energy meter and I want to see the measured data between 2 dates I choose, data which is stored in a database. I managed to pass the data through AJAX from the form to the PHP file that reads the database and I successfully receive the JSON encoded data into my console log.

The problem is that the chart is not populated with any data, it only shows an awkward time range.

JavaScript - included in index.php, not *.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('form.energy_consumption_datepicker').on('submit', function() {

    var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {

    var that = $(this),
    name = that.attr('name'),
    value = that.val();

    data[name] = value;
    });

    $.ajax ({

        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);

            $(function() {
        $('#custom_energy_consumption_chart').highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Instantaneous absorbed power'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'kW'
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value / 1000; // formatted number for kW
                    }
                }
            },

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<b>{point.y} W </b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: {
                            x1: 0,
                            y1: 0,
                            x2: 0,
                            y2: 1
                        },
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    },
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 3,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                color: '#00d5ff',
                type: 'area',
                name: 'Watts',
                data: response
            }]
        });

        });

        $(".custom_energy_consumption").show(350);

        }

    });
    return false;
});

});
```

index.php - parts

```
    <script src="../../js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/highcharts-more.js"></script>
    .
    .
    <div class="energyConsumption" style="width: auto; height: 400px; margin: 80px auto auto 80px; display:none;">

        <h3 align="left">Choose the period to display the energy consumption</h3>

        <form class="energy_consumption_datepicker" action="custom_chart.php" method="post">

            <div class="input-control text" id="fromDatepicker">

                <input name="fromDate" id="fromDatepicker_input" type="text" data-validate-func="date" data-validate-func="required" data-validate-hint="Please select a date" data-validate-hint-position="bottom">
                <span class="input-state-error mif-warning"></span>
                <span class="input-state-success mif-checkmark"></span>
                <button class="button"><span>From</span></button>

            </div>

            <div class="input-control text" id="toDatepicker">

                <input name="toDate" id="toDatepicker_input" type="text" data-validate-func="date" data-validate-func="required" data-validate-hint="Please select a date" data-validate-hint-position="bottom">
                <span class="input-state-error mif-warning"></span>
                <span class="input-state-success mif-checkmark"></span>
                <button class="button"><span>To</span></button>

            </div>

            <input type="submit" class="button primary" value="Show">

        </form>

        <div class="custom_energy_consumption" id="custom_energy_consumption_chart" style="width: auto; height: 400px; margin: 50px auto; display:none"></div>

    </div>
```

custom_chart.php

```
<?php

    $fromDate = $_POST["fromDate"];
    $toDate = $_POST["toDate"];

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $servername = "localhost";
    .
    .
    $dbname = "smart_meter";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM date) 'year', EXTRACT(month FROM date)-1 'month', EXTRACT(day FROM date) 'day', EXTRACT(hour FROM date) 'hour', EXTRACT(minute FROM date) 'minute', energy FROM energy_data WHERE date BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $customPc[] = "[Date.UTC(" . $row["year"] . "," . $row["month"] . "," . $row["day"] . "," .  $row["hour"] . "," .  $row["minute"] . ")," . $row["energy"] . "]";
        }
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
    $conn->close();

    echo json_encode(join($customPc, ','));

    ?>
```

Data received in console log:

> [Date.UTC(2016,2,8,14,35),1534],[Date.UTC(2016,2,8,14,35),1534],[Date.UTC(2016,2,8,14,35),1534],[Date.UTC(2016,2,8,14,35),1534],
>   ...
>   [Date.UTC(2016,2,9,18,18),1534],[Date.UTC(2016,2,9,18,18),1534],[Date.UTC(2016,2,9,18,19),1534],[Date.UTC(2016,2,9,18,19),1534]

I replaced response in 'data: response' with the received data but writing 'data: [console data here]' and it works great.

Does anyone have an idea what might be happening here? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is wrong.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $customPc[] = "[Date.UTC(" . $row["year"] . "," . $row["month"] . "," . $row["day"] . "," .  $row["hour"] . "," .  $row["minute"] . ")," . $row["energy"] . "]";
    }
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

Try with this.

```
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $counter = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $customPc[$counter] = array("year"=>date('Y',strtotime($row["year"])), "month"=>date('F',strtotime($row["month"])),"day"=>$row["day"],"hour"=>$row["hour"], "minute"=>$row["minute"],"energy"=> $row["energy"] );
        $counter ++;
    }
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting something like this: [Object, ..., Object]

Comment: I guess you don´t have do this echo json_encode(join($customPc, ','));

Try :echo json_encode($customPc);

And try use JSON.parse(response) in your javascript

Comment: Try to see on your console, the ajax response use, firebug extension for chrome or firefox.

Comment: I have tried with JSON.parse(response) with no luck. If I replace the received string in firebug console with the chart function variable it works. I think the problem is how I pass the received string to the chart function.

Comment: Try with jQuery.parseJSON(response); could you show me the response array to validate if the json format is correct.

Comment: I have already tried every possible sollution. I am not using json anymore. I use a string. I generate the string in PHP, pass it to the console and looks good, put it as a string in the date option, also works, but if I pass it to the chart as data: variable_name it messes up.

Comment: Could you paste your response string iguess the issue is on the response

Comment: My current response string is: [[Date.UTC(2016,2,8,14,35),1534],[Date.UTC(2016,2,8,14,35),1534],[Date.UTC(2016,2,14,14,55),1534],[Date.UTC(2016,2,14,14,55),1534]].

If I paste this string in my data: string_here it is ok.

But interesting thing I just found out, if I do a console.log([[Date.UTC(2016,2,8,14,35),1534],[Date.UTC(2016,2,8,14,35),1534],[Date.UTC(2016,2,14,14,55),1534],[Date.UTC(2016,2,14,14,55),1534]]); I get a [Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]] and if I open an array the Date.UTC() is parsed into something like: 1457447700000. Though, the energy parameter looks good.

Comment: I guess the format is not correct, what kind of highcharts are you using for this?

Comment: [link](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series), this exact chart with minor modifications

Comment: Did you try to parse this string to an object??

Comment: You're a god mister. I just used var test = eval('[' + response + ']'); and removed my first and last enclosing brackets [] from my initial string and it works. You have saved me hours of search and work. Thank you!

Comment: Try something like this :   in your ajax response use var  string_data = JSON.stringify(response); and then
var parse_data = JSON.parse(string_data); and in your highchart data put data:parse_data

Comment: Using the last method I get back to the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that functions in JSON are not evaluated. It means that your Date.UTC() is not triggered, so timestamps are not returned. The fix is remove Date.UTC() from your JSON and put there timestamps.

In PHP you can use the [date](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.date.php) function and multiply UNIX timestamps by 1000 ( convert to javascript timestamps)

Comment: No luck with this also. I don't know how to properly pass another time format for Highcharts.

Comment: In PHP you can use the strtotime() function which converts strings into the timestamp. Multiply the field by 1000 and push to json.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit too much here to check everything, but one big problem is the way you send the data back:

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $customPc[] = "[Date.UTC(" . $row["year"] . "," . $row["month"] . "," . $row["day"] . "," .  $row["hour"] . "," .  $row["minute"] . ")," . $row["energy"] . "]";
    }

...

echo json_encode(join($customPc, ','));
```

Using string concatenation and `join` will result in one big string enclosed in quotes like `"all the data concatenated here"`.

You need an actual nested array with all your datapoints so one long string does not result in anything useful for highcharts.

You should generate a nested array structure and send that as json to your javascript. Something like:

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Add an array with 2 values to your data array
        $customPc[] = array(
            "Date.UTC(" . $row["year"] . "," . $row["month"] . "," . $row["day"] . "," .  $row["hour"] . $row["minute"],
            $row["energy"]
        );
    }

...

// Encode the data array as json
echo json_encode($customPc);
```

I am not sure if the generated date will work like this, perhaps you need to generate the date itself directly in php instead, but this is a lot closer to what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the input. With your edit I get the error [link](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/14.com) in my console and the data looks like this: [Array[1], Array[1], ..., Array[1]]

Comment: @SebastianN. You should check in php first if the structure and data is what you need it to be, for example with a `var_dump($customPc)`.

Comment: I have already tried to investigate the console with firebug and the string I receive looks OK and if I replace it in the function it works. I think the problem is how I pass the received string to the chart function.